# Cannot search my documents in search in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I moved some sub-sites to my new site collection.

I cannot search my documents through search box.

I enabled all settings to search but still I am not able to search .

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: There is not even close to enough information in your question to allow it to be answered. Include some useful details and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: @jwpfox i am not able to search my documents using search box . It shows no results but i unable all the settings for search purpose but still my issue dint solve.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of stabs in the dark:

1. Is your document library setting allowing to be crawled? To check, go to your document library > Library Settings > Advanced > Allow items from this document library to appear in search results? > Yes
2. Are the documents published, or are they checked out / drafts. Depending on permissions, draft items will not appear in search results see this post > https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-2013-search-function-missing-documents/757ca4ed-2531-420e-af98-6093adaf7b67
3. Has the search engine (on the server) reported any access issues? Do the search crawler and super read etc have access to your sub sites?
4. Has a crawl run since you added your sites / documents?

Just some things to get you started. Good luck!